# docker mongodb replication on same server

Tags: mongodb, docker

I want to setup on my dev machine a mongodb replication, same machine running mongodb instances on docker.

so i have docker containers running mongodb instances on them, working, fine and setup.

// some images omitted

```
$ docker ps -a
0.0.0.0:49157->27017/tcp
0.0.0.0:49156->27017/tcp
0.0.0.0:49155->27017/tcp
```

then, on my PRIMARY, i tried adding something

```
PRIMARY> rs.add("172.17.0.141:27017")                                                                                                                                  
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "need most members up to reconfigure, not ok : 172.17.0.141:27017",
        "code" : 13144
}

//===============

PRIMARY> rs.add("0.0.0.0:27017")                                                                                                                                  
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "need most members up to reconfigure, not ok : 0.0.0.0:27017",
        "code" : 13144
}
```

how do i add mongodb instances inside containers to replication using docker?

Answer (score 0):

nvm, i solved my question.

from this post, http://version2beta.com/articles/mongod-replica-set-slave/, i give credit to the author.

i have disabled my journal to my slaves

```
storage:
   smallFiles: true
   journal:
   enabled: false
```

then get the IP from container

```
$ docker inspect e123
```

then in mongo-cli

```
PRIMARY> rs.add("172.17.0.150:27017")
```